# Equivalent of this code in Python

Tags: python, arduino, xbee

I need to send data in a specific format from my Python program. The goal is that I can send data from my Python on my PC to an XBee connected to an Arduino. This has been done from a program (running on an Arduino) but not Python (Python code usually have been the receiver).

```cpp
// allocate two bytes for to hold a 10-bit analog reading
uint8_t payload[7];
int value1 = 100; // data to be sent

payload[0] = value1 >> 8 & 0xff; // payload[0] = MSB.
payload[1] = value1 & 0xff; // 0xff = 1111 1111, i.e.
```

And finally sends the data with this command (using XBee library):

```cpp
Tx16Request tx_5001 = Tx16Request(0x5001, payload, sizeof(payload));
xbee.send(tx_5001);
```

In Python, using XBee Python library, I want to send this data but it should conform to this format so that I can use the existing code to read the data and convert it to useful value.

In summary, does anyone know what's the equivalent of the following code in Python?

```cpp
uint8_t payload[7];
int value1 = 100; // data to be sent

payload[0] = value1 >> 8 & 0xff; // payload[0] = MSB.
payload[1] = value1 & 0xff; // 0xff = 1111 1111, i.e.
```

On the receive side, I have the following to extract the value that can be used:

```cpp
uint8_t dataHigh = rx.getData(0);
uint8_t dataLow = rx.getData(1);
int value1 = dataLow + (dataHigh * 256);
```

Edit: I really don't need two bytes for my data, so I did a test by defining a byte in python data=chr(0x5A) and used that in my transmit, and in the received I used int value1 = analogHigh which returns 232 regardless what I define the data!

Answer (score 1):

You probably looking for [struct](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/struct.html) (to convert python int to unit8_t) I have used it to communicate with low level devices.

So

```
import struct
var = 25  # try 2**17 and see what happens
print(struct.pack('<H', var))  # b'\x00\x19'
print(struct.pack('>H', var))  # b'\x00\x19'
```

- As you can see this `>` or `<` changing bytes between Little and Big Endian.
- `H` is for short (uint16_t) and `B` is for unsigned char (uint8_t).

The `b''` is python bytes string that allow you to see bytes data.
So i would to suggest you to start from `xbee.send(b'\x45\x15')` and see what happens on the other side. If communication works then start to create function that convert python types to structure reperesents.

See also:
 [BitwiseOperators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators)

Comment: Can you give an example, I tried to use a=pack('hh1',100), and then passed 'a' to the payload of the XBee transmit but on the received did not get 100.

Comment: Yes. I will edit answer soon. You should more care about how it's represented. And don't know nothing about XBee - so can help only with struct or BitWiesOperators.

Answer (score -1):

There are different ways to handle this, one way is to do a for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < rx.getDataLength(); i++)
{
  Serial.print( rx.getData(i), HEX );
}
```

and extract the data from that string which there are so many ways to do it.